# VBA Loop Throw an Array Variable not defined

Tags: arrays, forms, vba, loops, controls

here it is my code in a vba module to set a property to multiple controls in just one line :

```
' General Declaration
Public Enum con1_enumLetAction
    cEnabled
    cDisabled
    cVisible
    cUnVisible
End Enum

' Public function in the same module

Public Function Con_LetArray(LetAction As con1_enumLetAction, ByRef TheArray As Variant)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim conControl As Control

    For i = LBound(TheArray) To UBound(TheArray)
        Set conControl = TheArray(i)

    Select Case LetAction
        Case cEnabled
            conControl.Enabled = True
        Case cDisabled
            conControl.Enabled = False
        Case cVisible
            conControl.Visible = True
        Case cUnVisible
            conControl.Visible = False
    End Select
    Next

End Function
```

I used this function in a form containing 4 option buttons and a command button

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    mcon1_.Con_LetArray cDisabled, Array(OptionButton1, OptionButton2, OptionButton3)

End Sub
```

what is the problem ?? an error "Variable not defined" and OptionButton2 heighlighted

Comment: Is this in a form module, or a regular module. Form control event handlers (like CommandButton1_Click() need to be in the form module for the form that CommandButton1 is on.

Comment: i made a module for general functions to import it in any project and use it with a form module to minimize and simplify the code reading and writing, bth, the code in the function just work fine if i put the array only as an argument, not the array and the enum, like : Public Function Con_DisableArray(ByRef TheArray As Variant) --- then use it in the form like this : mcon1_.Con_DisablArray Array(OptionButton1, OptionButton2, OptionButton3)

Comment: Do you have an OptionButton2 defined? Is there a second OptionButton on your form, and is it named OptionButton2?

Comment: Here it is a pic of my form http://imgur.com/a/McbrU and Code http://imgur.com/a/dZxE5

Comment: It compiles with no errors for me. Is the error a run-time error?

Comment: What's `mcon1_`? Why is `Con_LetArray()` a **Function** when it doesn't return anything? Have you tried just `Con_LetArray cDisabled, Array(OptionButton1, OptionButton2, OptionButton3)` - assuming you do have all those OptionButtons?

Comment: You only have one OptionButton. The others are CheckBox(es).

Comment: Option Explicit is on (in form amd in module) mcon1_ is the module name (module conttrol 1) the function acts here like a sub procedure http://imgur.com/a/nXOJC

Comment: OPPPS, Thanks Rich Holton yes it is just one , Sorry Friends

Comment: You have used `Public Con_LetArray(...)`, there is no need to include the module name if they are in the same Workbook. They way you use `Con_LetArray`, it should be a **Sub**. Or you can give it a purpose to return a Boolean to indicate if every control in the Array got modified successfully.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I added the module name prefix just to know where the function came from (in which module i write it if i need to modify the function in the future then reimport the module again in all projects), and yes but i prefere function even if it not return any values, thanks again, and the code is working now after i added another 3 option buttons http://imgur.com/a/g1DQg

Comment: FWIW - A function **always** returns a value, even if you are ignoring it.  The function's return value type will be `Variant` because you haven't explicitly stated anything else, and the value will be `Empty` (in a `Variant/Empty`) because you haven't explicitly set the return value to be anything else.  You should use a `Sub` if you don't want your code to return a value.